# Wordpress archive and container error?

Tags: wordpress, containers, archive, sidebar

My single.php, archive, index and category.php pages are all the same using this coding below...

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Lisa-beauty.co.uk
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="headpostedin"><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?> </div>

<div class="content" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><div class="headtitle"><?php the_title(); ?></div> 

<div class="postmetadata"></div>

<?php the_content(__('CONTINUE READING...')); ?>

<?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '
'); ?>

<div class="headposted"><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?> comments</div>

<?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>

<?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Everyone works fine on my whole website lisa-beauty.co.uk but as soon as I click my archives in my sidebar then on to a page http://lisa-beauty.co.uk/lisa-beauty/?m=201509&paged=4 my whole container and sidebar are completely off but on other pages they are ok in my archive.

What could be causing the issue?

here is my coding from my header.php and footer.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name="description" content="Beauty uk blogger">
<meta name="keywords" content="blogger, beauty, fashion, make up">
<meta name="author" content="Lisa Robinson">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Lisa's Beauty UK Blog!</title>

<style type="text/css" media="screen"> @import url(/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve1/style.css);</style>

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body>
<a name="top"></a>
<div id="container">
<div id="header" onclick="window.location='http://lisa-beauty.co.uk'">
</div>





<div id="content">
<div class="content">
</br>


</div>
```

footer

```html
<div id="foot">
<div id="footer-wrapper">

</div>
</div>

<div class="top">
<a href="#top" title="Go up"><u>&#8593; up</u></a>
</div> 

<div class="left">
<div class="copyright">
Copyright 2015 www.lisa-beauty.co.uk <u>All rights reserved</u> | Powered by Wordpress | Theme by <a href="http://www.akaleez.co.uk/"><u>Akaleez</u></a>
</div>
</div> 





<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a problem with your mark-up i guess, somewhere you are closing a div where you should not, but i can't follow the mark-up to tell you where, it is too badly writted. I would say that your best option is to re-write your markup from scratch.

Comment: It is very strange, i removed a div from the comments or archive.php then one page that had the sidebar and container error went ok but then my other pages went wrong. Seems like its only on specific pages for example this one http://lisa-beauty.co.uk/lisa-beauty/?m=201504&paged=2

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely being caused by a rogue closing div somewhere. However, as sticksu says it's very difficult to debug this code.

Some general pointers:

**1) Indent your code**

It's far easier to debug this

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <div class="headpostedin">
    <?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

    <div class="headtitle">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="postmetadata">
    </div>

    <?php the_content(__('CONTINUE READING...')); ?>

    <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', ''); ?>

    <div class="headposted">
      <?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?> comments
    </div>

    <?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>

    <?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>

  </div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

than what you've posted above.

**2. If you're using `<br />` tags they should be like that rather than `</br>`**

**3. Validate your code.**

If you're ever having layout issues like this, run your code through the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and 99% of the time it will give you some great clues as to the underlying issue.

I think the main issue is with this line:

```
<div class="content" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
```

as you have an extra quote and close bracket in there. Try this instead:

```
<div class="content" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
```

Also note in the example above I've moved that final closing `</div>` at the bottom to be inside the loop, as it's good practice to close a div at the same level as abstraction as when you open it (the reason being that if there were no results returned the opening div would not be returned but the closing div would have been returned regardless, which would have then broken the page).

Comment: Think I have figured out an issue, as soon as I deactivate a plugin i installed two days ago my whole site is messed up which is not right since the theme has been ok before the plugin was installed. I am using the plugin Ultimate Social Media PLUS